Kafka behind reverse-proxy
My Kafka cluster, made by 3 brokers (kafka1:9092, kafka2:9094 and kafka3:9096) is mounted on a remote server which is accesible by internet (the domain is public).
The server is protected by strict firewall policies (that I cannot change) that make it accessible only through port 443 (so HTTPS).
In practice, I cannot point directly to the port 9092,9094,and 9096 from outside. To interact with the Kafka cluster I assume to do not use a Kafka REST proxy to publish to /consume from the cluster.
There is a way to manage the common interaction (publish, consume and subscribe) with the cluster, in some way, reverse proxying the request from https to the cluster?

A REST Proxy is common way.

It's a bit advanced, but if you want to keep using the Kafka protocol (and not HTTP), a Kafka proxy would do the trick (using 443 instead of 909x), combined to SNI, to use subdomains (one per broker) instead of ports (as you have only 1 port).

Do you have some reference to this approach?
